# Forcefully remove a physical drive from a LVM volume group

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

Some time ago I added a physical disk to a volume group I have before formatting the disk. I've been looking for a while how to fix the mess but I couldn't find anything. I guess that formatting the disk now (inside the vg) is not an option and that I should  first forcefully remove it from the volume group and then format it, but when using `vgreduce` even with the force flag says the disk is still in use.

What can I do?

edit* this is what pvdisplay tells me about the disk:

```
 --- Physical volume ---
 PV Name               /dev/sdc1
 VG Name               datavg
 PV Size               745.06 GiB / not usable 3.45 MiB
 Allocatable           yes (but full)
 PE Size               4.00 MiB 
 Total PE              190734
 Free PE               0
 Allocated PE          190734
 PV UUID               983nT1-PMwL-21Fz-tGw4-1ynZ-4JP9-s5OmGv
```

`pvmove` asks me to find free space for the ghost data that is inside the disk, but I don't have any spare disks.

Comment: Before doing vgreduce have you done pvmove? See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/disk_remove_ex.html

Comment: Yes, that's what had popped in my first google searches, but I can't use `pvmove` here AFAIK, because the system thinks the disk is full and I don't have free space for all that ghost data to purge later unplugging a different, and empty, disk.

Comment: 1.  what do you mean by "formatting the disk"?  You don't need to "format" a block device before adding it to a VG.  You just add it and then start creating LVs, which then get formatted with a filesystem and mounted (or used to provide a virtual disk for a VM etc). Or did you mean to secure-erase /dev/sdc1 first but forgot?   2. are there other disks/partitions in VG datavg?  2. please edit your Q and show output of `vgdisplay datavg` and `lvdisplay datavg`. 3.  If you don't have any other disks to `pvmove` the data to, you'll have to get one - you'll only need a 1TB drive and they're cheap.

Comment: Damn, I'm so stupid. That was literally my problem; I thought you had to build the file system before adding it to the volume group. Not sure where I got the idea but it just stuck with me. This isn't even the first time I do this. Thank you a lot, even though I'm sorry to make such a silly question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [LVM HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/removepvsfromvg.html), you should use `pvmove` for moving the extents first:

In *11.6. Removing physical volumes from a volume group*,

> - Make sure that the physical volume isn't used by any logical volumes by using the [**`pvdisplay`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pvdisplay) command, then
> - If the physical volume is still used you will have to migrate the data to another physical volume using [**`pvmove`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pvmove).

That's assuming you have other physical volumes in the group (otherwise you'd have just deleted the whole setup).

Comment: Forgot to say that I can't use `pvmove`, I've been trying it intermittently for some weeks now so I don't remember everything I did, sorry for that. Edited the answer with relevant information. Since the disk is unformatted, my system thinks it is full. I don't have any place to reallocate all that ghost data, if I had I'd have done it that way in the first place.